# Is there any exit editing mode for UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The flow is something like that... The user see a UITableView, when the user click the "edit", the user can delete the UITableView's cell, after that, he /she click done to confirm. Which method is called when the user click the done key? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `UITableViewController` it's `setEditing:` with `NO` as argument.

Answer (score 2):

By overriding the UITableViewController's setEditing:animated: method, you'll get the message you are looking for.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        // User tapped the edit button
    } else {
        // User tapped the done button
    }
}
```